# Why some queries can be queried again and others not?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For me, this is about `.reverse` vs `.order('id DESC')`

If I have

```
history = where(user_id: user).order('id DESC')
```

I can still perform another query like `history.where(person_id: person)`

If I have

```
history = where(user_id: user).reverse
```

I get: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'where' for #<Array:0x000001031a3408>`

Is this because these functions differ on the array type they should be used with (associative vs regular arrays)? What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ActiveRecord query methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) (e.g. `where`, `order`, `joins`, etc.) return an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html). This allows you to chain the methods to build a query, and the query is not executed until you use the actual data.

Since `reverse` is not a query method, it operates on the actual data in Ruby, and thus the query is executed so that Ruby may operate on the data, and it returns an `Array`. Since now you have only data (in the form of an `Array`) and not an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, you cannot call another query method.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot. Excellent explanation

Answer (score 2):

`reverse` is a method outside the activerecord query interface, whereas `order` is in the interface. Once you execute `reverse`, you don't have a resource anymore, but an array. You'll need to execute any sql methods (like `where`) before you reverse the output.